# pine (Alpine) with GMail 2-step Authentication enabled?

Tags: email, authentication, imap, alpine-mail

I always get a message:

```
IMAP Authentication canceled
```

And then:

```
Retrying plain authentication after [ALERT] application-specific
```

When I look at my google security settings I can't find any option to create an application specific password to associate with Alpine on my laptop.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/bSQZVxRIjb0

Comment: If you have 2-step verification you can generate an "App password", 16 characters long, only for your alpine authentication. You can generate this token once you have logged in "youraccount.google.com" in the section "Sign-in & security" -> "App password".

Comment: It's https://myaccount.google.com/ and I don't see the "App password" link you are referencing. There is a 'connected apps & sites' section which doesn't include an option to generate a token.

Comment: My bad, I missed a step. "Sign-in & security" -> "Signin in to Google" -> "App password".

Comment: that's the crucial step @andreatsh for the 2FA or MFA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as recommended by Andreatsh in the comments.

Go to http://myaccount.google.com

Then  "Sign-in & security" -> "Signin in to Google" -> "App password"

Once you create the one time password you will also have to run:

```
touch ~/.pine-passfile
```

This makes it so when you enter the gmail folder on Alpine you will be asked if you want to save the password.

Comment: this is very, very useful.  Also, there's an "app password" which you can (unsafely) store locally if you have MFA or 2FA enabled.