# Pine Email Client and MFA

Tags: email

Can anyone describe how to deploy a Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) solution (such as DUO) to the text based email client Pine (out of the University of Washington)?

Many University's have distributed email environments with fierce pocket's of independent IT groups, some of whom run their own Mail Transport Agents (MTA) and whose membership are loyal to particular email client solutions.

Deploying an MFA product (such as DUO) across an enterprise is impeded by support issues such as this.

I haven't been able to find out of Pine supports DUO or even if anyone is doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327803/pine-alpine-with-gmail-2-step-authentication-enabled

Comment: Not a duplicate at all.  Read the two questions.  The first is about Google's security settings specific to Alpine and this one is about setting up Pine (or Alpine) to use MFA (or DUO).  This question is NOT asking how to generate an application specific password (in Google) but how to enable MFA.  The only thing these questions have in common is the mail client.